# How do you revoke app login tokens on an Android device?

Tags: android, security, passwords

Is there a centralized command in Android to revoke the login tokens for all apps, or do you have to go in each app to delete it?

I'm not talking about website passwords stored in Chrome, but the state of the user being logged into an app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific? When you say "delete all app passwords" are you referring to removing **stored** passwords from the device itself? Are you referring to "logging out" all apps that are currently logged in? Or something else entirely?

Comment: There's no centralized storage mechanism for passwords.  In fact, saving a password someone logged in with is a big security flaw-  any halfway decent engineer would be using a login token instead.  And most just store those in their private directory.  So no, there is no way to do this.

Comment: @SentientFlesh: I realize that my question was unclear. What I had in mind was logging out of all apps
@ Gabe Sechan: thanks for the explanation, I definitely need to educate myself on the subject :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you clarified in the comments, you're looking to log out all users signed into every app on the device, mass removing login tokens.

Clearing the application data for a specific app will revoke the login token and sign the user out. Programmatically this is not feasible because Android SDK restricts what access apps have to other apps. For managing packages, take a look at the [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) documentation.

Additionally, apps without a public API for managing login tokens will not respond to a program trying to force a logout.

So universally, no, there is no magic bullet for revoking all login tokens.

But here's an example of what the workflow would look like, from [Facebook's SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/login/loginmanager.html/):

```
// Initialize 
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
// Log out the currently logged in user
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Different apps will have different methods, but any public API will have a very similar workflow.